# Batch file: run a program that matches a substring

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe

I am writing a batch script to install programs silently, the problem I have is that each exe file to install the program has a version number after the name of the file, so (7zip v9.20.exe).

I need to write a batch script that will search a folder for the file regardless of the version number, so only matching 7zip in the file and then executing that file to run the silent installation.

I have the part with the silent installation down it is just that I need a way to search a folder for 7zip, without the version number, and run that exe.

Comment: Why does this have to be a batch script?

Comment: what is the format of the version number and is it consistent in all cases? i.e. are examples like the following possible: `7zip 9.20.exe`, `7zip V9.9.20.exe`, `7zip 9.2000000.exe`?

Comment: The version number is consistent as 7zip v9.20.exe, it has to be a batch script because I am creating an auto-installation script to install specific apps silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "7zip *.exe" file is located in anyone of %PATH% folders:

```
for %%f in ("7zip *.exe") do set filename="%%~$PATH:f"
rem To execute the filename:
%filename% parameters ...
```

If the "7zip *.exe" file is not located in %PATH%:

```
set baseFolder=C:\path\of\base\folder\for\7zip
for /R %baseFolder% %%f in ("7zip *.exe") do set filename="%%~Ff"
```